# Issue while integrating bootstrap template in a django project

Tags: django, django-templates, django-bootstrap4

I am trying to integrate bootstrap template with one of my Django project. I mostly succeeded in doing so and was able to render all the images and other stuff of the template to my django project. But the actual formatting of the template was lost while integrating. I found the below error while doing so, need help to understand and find remedy to the error. Below is the error from my cmd.

```
 File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\_os.py", line 46, in safe_join
    'component ({})'.format(final_path, base_path))
django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (S:\stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com\bootstrap\4.4.1\js\bootstrap.min.js) is located outside of the base path component (C:\Users\DELL\community@with_final_template 7 Feb 2020\static)
[09/Feb/2020 10:46:44] "GET /static/https%3A/stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[09/Feb/2020 10:46:44] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 6333
```

## settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Please show us how you are trying to load the bootstrap assets in your template - that is where the issue is.

Comment: added the settings file where I loaded the static path and matched the same by calling the static in the template file.

Comment: That isn't quite what I was asking for. We need to see where in your template you are trying to load the external bootstrap JS. Where is `stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js` referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to see your template code to be sure, but it seems that in your template you have done this:

```
<script src="{% static 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js` %}"></script>
```

... which is invalid. The `static` template tag can only be used for assets that are stored in your static directory. External libraries like this should just be referenced as a regular URL:

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```